# My Facebook page has been redirected to another account

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a facebook page at the following URL: https://www.facebook.com/111trio

Unfortunately since today, when someone try to access my facebook page from the URL, it is automatically redirected to the following profil: https://www.facebook.com/evelyn.lilly.9

Curiously, my facebook page is still accessible from a smartphone.

I also noticed that when typing https://www.facebook.com/111trio/ (with an extra "/"), I am not redirected to https://www.facebook.com/evelyn.lilly.9

Finally the last thing is that I have this problem only on Chrome (Safari and Firefox don't do the redirection).

Any idea how it is possible? How can I recover my page?

Comment: Have you seen this problem on more than one computer? I just tried in Chrome (Win7) and didn't get redirected.

Comment: Yes. It seems I'm not the only one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRPOR48lY9Y

Comment: Disable all of your browser extensions. It could be one of them.

Comment: I disabled the extension and the problem was fixed. I reenabled the extension and the problem was still fixed. I suspect there was a bug on facebook that has been solved in the mean time.